# How do I read a Roberta tokenizer from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bert-language-model

I have saved a Robert tokenizer (autotokenizer) which I have used for a Roberta model to a GCS bucket. I get the error:

```
HFValidationError: Repo id must use alphanumeric chars or '-', '_', '.', '--' and '..' are forbidden, '-' and '.' cannot start or end the name, max length is 96: '[<_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f3cbf1db770>, <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f3cb5c61a70>, <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f3cb5c611d0>]'.
```

I have saved the tokenizer to a Google Cloud Storage bucket where it appears as three json files ("special_tokens_map.json", "tokenizer.json", and "tokenizer_config.json"). How can I load them so I can use them for retraining/inference (for example within a Vertex AI notebook). I am trying to load them in the same way as the model, by downloading each blob (json file) as a string and then converted those strings using BytesIO. I put a list containing those converted strings into AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained().

```
tokeniser_parts_names=["special_tokens_map.json", "tokenizer.json", "tokenizer_config.json"]
    
tokeniser_parts=[BytesIO(__bucket.get_blob(tokeniser_folder+part).download_as_string()) for part in tokeniser_parts_names]
    
tokeniser = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(tokeniser_parts)
```

The model loads correctly but the tokeniser doesn't load. I realise you're supposed to put a directory in the .from_pretrained method, but how do I do this using a GCS bucket?

Comment: Show your code here, please.

Comment: @erip , I have done that thanks!